# Generate Data-Driven Unit-Tests in Java

Tags: java, maven, code-generation

Let's say I have a junit method

```
public class BusinessClassTest {

    private BusinessClass fixture;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
       //the following two paths reside in the man/test/resources folder
       String inputPath = "/fixtures/1/input";
       String expectedPath = "/fixtures/1/expected";
       validatedFixture(inputPath, expectedPath);
    }

    private void valiateFixture(String inputPath, String expectedPath) {
        //inputData = load the input data
        //feed it to a fixture
        //actual = fixture.process(inputData)
        //expectedData = loadExpectedData
        //validate(expectedData, actualData);
     }
}
```

Now let's assume that I have 20 folders under fixtures.  How can I loop through the folders and for each folder generate a method similar to

```
    @Test
    public void test{test_number}() {
       //the following two paths reside in the man/test/resources folder
       String inputPath = "/fixtures/{test_number}/input";
       String expectedPath = "/fixtures/{test_number}/expected";
       validatedFixture(inputPath, expectedPath);
    }
```

Idlealy I would like to build this class out as part of maven.

---

Update

I'm using velocity to generate the class however, not sure how to engage the code generation from maven...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using what Matt has listed for the File system traversal, you could use a parameterized test to perform your numerable validations.

This approach will provide you with well named tests based on the arguments to the @Parameters(name) annotation.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith (Parameterized.class)
public class BusinessClassTest{
    @Parameters(name="{0}:{1}")
    public static Collection<Object[]> getTestPaths() {
        Collection<Object[]> allTests = new ArrayList<>();

         File file = new File("/fixtures/");
          String[] dirs = file.list((current, name) -> 
                            new File(current, name).isDirectory());

          for (String testNumber : dirs) {
            String inputPath = "/fixtures/" + dirs + "/input";
            String expectedPath = "/fixtures/" + dirs + "/expected";
            allTests.add(asConstructorArguments(inputPath, expectedPath));
          }

        return allTests;
    }

    private static Object[] asConstructorArguments(String inputPath, String expectedPath) {
        return new Object[]{inputPath, expectedPath};
    }

    private final String inputData;
    private final String expectedData;
    private final Fixture fakedFixture;


    public BusinessClassTest(String input, final String expected) {
        this.inputData = input;
        this.expectedData = expected;
        fakedFixture = new Fixture() {          
            @Override
            public String process(String path) {
                return expected;
            }
        };
    }

    @Test
    public void validateFixture() {
        //feed it to a fixture
        String actualData = fakedFixture.process(inputData);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedData, actualData);
    }

    //Interface to emulate your API
    public interface Fixture {
        String process(String path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to dynamically build the test classes? Another approach would be to iterate over all the subdirectories of your `fixtures` base path and then call the `validatedFixture` directly for each path. Find a sample in Java8 below:

```
@Test
public void bigTest {
  File file = new File("/fixtures/");
  String[] dirs = file.list((current, name) -> 
                    new File(current, name).isDirectory());

  for (String testNumber : dirs) {
    String inputPath = "/fixtures/" + dirs + "/input";
    String expectedPath = "/fixtures/" + dirs + "/expected";
    // omit the test method and call validation directly
    validatedFixture(inputPath, expectedPath);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this...I'm aware of this approach.  I need the actual methods so that I can annotate them...